# Executing KornShell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I can't execute my KornShell (ksh) script without the `ksh` command. I included `#!/bin/ksh` in the first line of the script but when I try to execute it by name only, it says no such file or directory. Can someone help me?

Comment: use `./Your_Script_Name`

To find where `ksh` is actually loaded , try `which ksh`.

It might also be that your `ksh` is not in the path `/bin/ksh` .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- make sure that `ksh` is correctly installed in `/bin/ksh`

  try `which ksh` from the command-line.

  consider `#! /usr/bin/env ksh` for more portability.
- for executing a `script` run from the command-line `./script` in the directory where `script` exist.
- If you want to execut the `script` from any directory without `./` prefix, you have to add the path to your `script` to the `PATH` environment variable, add this line

  `export PATH="path_to_your_script":$PATH`

  to you  `~/.kshrc` file.

Comment: yes with ./script it works, but when I used bash script it could be execute with just Script.sh. So can I make it work that way with korn shell?

Comment: add the directory where `script.sh` exist to your PATH.

Comment: when I add it to PATH ( PATH=$PATH:/home/myacc ) it is ok, but when I close the terminal and open it again, PATH has not saved what I added. What is going on here?